# Formal proof about why $\operatorname{E}[(X-\operatorname{E}[X|Y])^2|Y]$ is minimal

Tags: statistics, reference-request, proof-explanation, conditional-expectation

Reading different books of mathematical statistics (that I remember now: Lehmann and Casella in their point estimation book, Batthacharya et al. in their mathematical statistics book, and probably some other books) I found this assertion without proof many times:

> Let $X\in L_2$ and $h$ any measurable function, then the expression $\operatorname{E}[(X-a)^2]$ is minimized when $a=\operatorname{E}[X]$. **Therefore it follows** that $\operatorname{E}[(X-h(Y))^2|Y]$ is minimized a.s. when $h(Y)=\operatorname{E}[X|Y]$.

I understand why $\operatorname{E}[(X-a)^2]$ is minimized when $a=\operatorname{E}[X]$, this can be shown easily in different ways, however I dont see how **from this statement** it follows that $\operatorname{E}[(X-h(Y))^2|Y]$ is almost sure minimal when $h(Y)=\operatorname{E}[X|Y]$. Can someone show me the formal detailed steps of this assertion, or at least, give me some reference where these details are explained carefully?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint (almost solution).**
$$E[(X-h(Y))^2]=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(x-h(y))^2f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy=$$
$$=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_Y(y) \left( \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} (x-h(y))^2f_{X|Y}(x|y)dx \right) dy=$$
$$=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_{Y}(y)E_y(X-h(y))^2dx,$$
where $E_y[X]=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}xf_{X|Y}(x|y)dx$.

But the marhematical expectation under the integral attains the minimum, when $h(y)=E_y[X]$.

Comment: @Masacroso, yes, my fault, i have edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

I want to generalize a bit the answer of @greyls using a theorem of measure theory about disintegrations of measures: suppose that $\rho $ is a measurable non-negative function, then

$$
\int_{\Omega }\operatorname{E}[\rho (X,Y)|Y](\omega )\Pr (d\omega ) =\int_{\mathcal{Y}}\operatorname{E}[\rho (X,s)|Y=s]F_Y(d s)=\int_{\mathcal{Y}}\int_{\mathcal{X}}\rho (t,s) F_{X|Y}(s,d t)F_Y(ds)
$$

where $F_{X|Y}(s,dt)F_Y(ds)$ is just the disintegration of the measure $F_{X,Y}(dt,ds)$, and $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ are respectively the codomain of $X$ and $Y$. Therefore $\operatorname{E}[\rho (X,Y)|Y]$ is minimal a.s. if and only if $\int_{\mathcal{X}}\rho (t,s) F_{X|Y}(s,d t)$ is minimal for almost every $s$. Now the statement
$$
\operatorname{E}[(X-c)^2]\geqslant \operatorname{E}[(X-\operatorname{E}[X])^2] \text{ for all }c\in \mathbb{R}
$$

is equivalent to say that
$$
\int_{\mathcal{X}}(t-c)^2 F_X(dt)\geqslant \int_{\mathcal{X}}(t-\mu)^2 F_X(dt)\text{ for all $c$ whenever }\mu=\int_{\mathcal{X}}t F_X(dt)
$$
Thus for the case of $\rho (s,t)=|h(s)-t|^2$, for some measurable function $h$, the above translates to
$$
h(s)=\int_{\mathcal{X}}t F_{X|Y}(s,dt)=\operatorname{E}[X|Y=s]
$$
to make every $\int_{\mathcal{X}}(t-h(s))^2 F_{X|Y}(s,dt)$ minimal, what is equivalent to the statement of the minimality of $\operatorname{E}[(X-\operatorname{E}[X|Y])^2|Y]$. This procedure is also useful to show that $\operatorname{E}[|X-h(Y)||Y]$ is minimal when $h(s)$ is a median of the distribution $F_{X|Y}(s,dt)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$E[(X-h(Y))^2|Y]=E[(X-E[X|Y]+E[X|Y]-h(Y))^2|Y]=$$
$$=E[(X-E[X|Y])^2|Y]+E[(E[X|Y]-h(Y))^2|Y]+2E[(X-E[X|Y])(E[X|Y]-h(Y))|Y]$$
But:
$$E[(E[X|Y]-h(Y))^2|Y]=(E[X|Y]-h(Y))^2$$
And:
$$E[(X-E[X|Y])(E[X|Y]-h(Y))|Y]=(E[X|Y]-h(Y))E[(X-E[X|Y])|Y]=0$$
Therefore it must be:$(E[X|Y]-h(Y))^2=0$ and $E[X|Y]=h(Y)$